# stopping sprites from overlapping/going through each other

Tags: java, 2d, sprite, collision-detection, collision

In the game that I am currently working on I don't want the zombies to be able to overlap each other. Therefore, I want to make it so that when they do collide with each other they will get moved back to the x and y they were on right before the collision.

I have tried to make it so that it updates the zombies' x and y position as long as they do not collide with any zombies with this statement `if(!r1.intersects(r2))` (`r1` and `r2` are the bounding boxees for the two zombies that collide) and then setting the zombie x and y to the x and y that was determined in the `if(!r1.intersects(r2))` statement in this statement `if(r1.intersects(r2))`.

For some reason all the zombies will overlap and look like only one zombie. I guess all the zombies will teleport to that x and y when two collide, but I have done it so that only the zombies that collides will get afected. It works when I make it so that one of the zombies will move it's y and x up with 1 pixel and the other one will move it's x any y down with one pixel, but the problem then is that in the beginning, when there are a lot of zombies, they will all move a lot faster than the ones later on.

I have tried to solve this problem by making the zombies faster every time one of them dies but I haven't gotten that to work for some reason. I tried that by having a `double` called speed that got the value of the zombie speed and then doing something like `speed += .1;` in the method that checked the collision between the player bullet and the zombie but they still didn't get any faster when i shot one of them. To see if you can figuer out why that doesn't work heres the code for adding zombie object to an `ArrayList` making them move and checking collision for them.

Method that add 56 zombies to an `ArrayList` and makes all of them spawn at an random location.

```
public void initZombie(){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < 56; i++){
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            int xSize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
            int ySize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight() + 300;
            int thaXSize = xSize + 800;
            double randomXSpawn = Math.random() * thaXSize + xSize;
            double randomYSpawn = Math.random() * ySize + 0;
            zombies.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
        }
    }
```

Method for making the zombies move towards the player.

```
public void zombieMovement(){
        for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){ 
            Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
            Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
            if(z.getY() > player.getY()){
                z.setY(z.getY() - z.getSpeed());
            }
            if(z.getY() < player.getY()){
                z.setY(z.getY() + z.getSpeed());
            }
            if(z.getX() > player.getX()){
                z.setX(z.getX() - z.getSpeed());
            }
            if(z.getX() < player.getX()){
                z.setX(z.getX() + z.getSpeed());
            }
            if(z.isAlive()){
                z.move();
            }else{ 
                zombies.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Method for checking collision between the player and a zombie and between a bullet and a zombie.

```
public void checkCollision(){
        Rectangle r3 = player.getBounds();
        for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
            Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
            Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
            if(r3.intersects(r2)){
                timer.start();
                if(!player.getInvincibility()){
                    player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + 10);
                    player.setInvincibility(true);
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayList bullet = player.getBullet();
        for(int j = 0; j < bullet.size(); j++){
            Bullet b = (Bullet) bullet.get(j);
            Rectangle r1 = b.getBounds();
            for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
                Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
                Rectangle r2 = z.getBounds();
                if(r1.intersects(r2)){
                    b.setVisible(false);
                    z.setAlive(false);
                    int newScore = Integer.parseInt(player.getScore());
                    newScore += 10;
                    z.setSpeed(z.getSpeed() + 1);
                    player.setScore("" + newScore);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for checking collision between zombie and zombie that I have put seperate directly in the `run()` method.

```
checkCollision();   
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
                Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
                zombieMovement();
                for(int j = i + 1; j < zombies.size(); j++){
                    Zombie z2 = (Zombie) zombies.get(j);
                    Rectangle r1 = z.getBounds();
                    Rectangle r2 = z2.getBounds();
                    if(r1.intersects(r2)){
                        if(z.getX() > z2.getX()){
                            z.setX(z.getX() + 1);
                        }
                        if(z.getX() < z2.getX()){
                            z.setX(z.getX() - 1);
                        }
                        if(z2.getX() > z.getX()){
                            z2.setX(z2.getX() + 1);
                        }
                        if(z2.getX() < z.getX()){
                            z2.setX(z2.getX() - 1);
                        }
                        if(z.getY() > z2.getY()){
                            z.setY(z.getY() + 1);
                        }
                        if(z.getY() < z2.getY()){
                            z.setY(z.getY() - 1);
                        }
                        if(z2.getY() > z.getY()){
                            z2.setY(z2.getY() + 1);
                        }
                        if(z2.getY() < z.getY()){
                            z2.setY(z2.getY() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have also tried to check the collision before it happens, by checking if the spot is occupied before moving the zombie there, but I never managed to figure out how I could check if the spot already was occupied by another zombie.

So theres three things that I could use to make the zombies unable to overlap/go through each other: making the zombie move to its previous position, making the zombies faster everytime one dies, or checking if the spot the zombie tries to move to is already occupied. You can choose witch of these you want to help me with - it doesn't really matter as long as it works.

***Edit:*** I figured it out myself, I just had to move `zombieMovement();` outside of the code that checked the collision for zombies but if you could answer on how to check if the spot already is occupied I would appreciate it because I'm sure that thats an better way for doing it on.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `zombieMovement();` outside of the code that checkes the collision for zombies